# How Android O affect background service to reduce battery drain?

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I create a `service` that start a new `thread` to do stuff. In **Android O**, the android document said if the `service` is not a `foreground service`, then it will be stopped by the system. But I tested the following code, the `service` is destroyed but the `thread` is still running.

My question is how the system can save user's battery if the thread is allowed to be run even if the `service` is stopped?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void startService(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
  }

  public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
  }

}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println("run in service: ");
        }
      }
    }).start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("service onDestroy");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test this behaviour for longer hours ? I had the same set-up with a service (started via main thread) running a worker thread inside. Upon testing the set-up for longer duration like 2-3 days. You will notice that system shuts down the entire process. So you can not rely on doing the background execution with a worker thread. Better approach is to use periodic or timed Jobs.